# Making a system of second-order ODEs chaotic

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Consider a system of N linear 2nd-order OEDs, describing a system of coupled one-dimensional harmonic oscillators, with couplings given by matrix A and positions $X = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$, we have

$X'' = A*X$

How can this system become chaotic by introducing an extra term? For instance, would it become chaotic by adding a higher-order term like $f_{(x_1)}$ to the equation of the first oscillator, such as $x_1^2$ or $x_1^4$? Or, do I need to add nonlinear coupling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linearly coupled anharmonic oscillators exhibit chaotic dynamics, a simple example studied by [Steep, Louw, and Villet](http://www.publish.csiro.au/?act=view_file&file_id=PH870587.pdf) is

$$\ddot{x}_1=-A x_1-ax_1^3-cx_2$$
$$\ddot{x}_2=-Ax_2-ax_2^3-cx_1$$

Comment: Thanks, very informative. I don't have upvoting power right now. Can chaos happens with $x_1^2$ or $x_1^4$ terms? I suppose with the first term it'd be integrable?

Answer (score 1):

You can get chaos with a cubic term for $x_1$.
In applied dyanmical systems, there has been considerable interest in last decade to study systems of the following form:
$\ddot{x_1}=-ax_1^3+\epsilon(x_1-x_2)$

$\ddot{x_2}=bx_2+\epsilon(x_2-x_1)$, where usually $\epsilon<<1$, and rest of coefficients are $O(1)$.

Physically, this corresponds to weakly & linearly coupled oscillators , and presence of a strong nonlinearity (a PURELY nonlinear spring attached to first). The solutions of this class of equations have been seen to be chaotic for a subset of parameters.

See for example: Energy pumping in nonlinear mechanical oscillators:Part 1 by Gendelman et. al. Journal of Applied Mechanics.

Comment: QPiyush I'll upvote as soon as I get enough rep. Question for you: Is there any studies for adding $x_1^2$ or $x_1^4$ terms?